# I have to fing avg of a number of arrays of positive integers with 0 marking the end of each of the array

Tags: python-3.x

I'm given a range of arrays of positive integers with 0 marking the end of each of the array.I have to find avg. of each array ,rounded to nearest integer, with answer separated by spaces.

Any help will be highly appreciated.....

```
n=int(input(' Please enter the number of arrays:- '))
ans=[]
for i in range(n):
    def avg_of_array(nums):
        for j in range(len(nums)):
            if nums[j]==0:
                avg=int(sum(nums)/(len(nums)-1))
                ans.append(avg)
            if nums[j]==0 and nums[j+1]<len(nums):
                avg=int(sum(nums)/(j-1))
                ans.append(avg)
    print('The answers:- {n1}'.format(n1=' '.join(map(lambda x:str(x),ans))))
```

Comment: formatting man, your code is totally unreadable

Comment: You cannot access to variables inside avg_of_array outside of the function.

Comment: Function definition inside of for loop, which you aren't calling and also returns None. Well... You should check there for sure.